# How many elements of order $6$ are in $S_7$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many elements of order $6$ are in $S_7$?

I understand that the forms of the permutations that have order $6$ are:

$(abcdef)(g), (abc)(de)(fg), (abc)(de)$ so there should be $7!*3 / 7$ elements?

I feel like I'm missing something here.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear to me how do you get $7!\cdot 3/7$. Please give the count of each type of permutations separately.

Comment: Could someone explain in more detail the cycle characterization permutation of order six?

Answer (score 4):

For the first type, there are $7$ ways to pick $g$, then $6!$ ways to arrange $a,\ldots,f$ - but reach 6-cycle is obtained $6$ times. That makes $7\cdot \frac{6!}{6}$.

For the second type, there are $7\choose 3$ ways to pick $a,b,c$, and as above $\frac{3!}3$ ways to form a cycle from them. Apart from that, if we fix $d$ among the remaining elements, there are $3$ ways to pick the element $d$ is mapped to; after that all is determined. This makes ${7\choose 3}\cdot \frac{3!}3\cdot 3$.

For the third kind, there are ${7\choose 3}\cdot\frac{3!}3$ ways to obtain the 3-cycle, and the $4\choose 2$ ways to obtain the 2-cycle from the remaining elements. That makes ${7\choose 3}\cdot\frac{3!}3\cdot {4\choose 2}$.

Now add.

Comment: For the second type, If there's three spots available and $7$ items to choose from, why wouldn't it be $7*6*5$ ways to pick $a,b,c$?

Comment: Let us consider only the second case once, and treat it in a slightly different manner. So first, we pick $3$ out of $7$ elements in $^7C_3$ ways, and then they may be arranged in a cycle in $3!/3$ ways. Next, we pick $2$ elements out of the remaining $4$ in $^4C_2$ ways and arrange these in a cycle in $2!/2=1$ ways. There is only one choice for the remaining cycle. This, now, gives us $^7C_3\cdot \frac{3!}{3}\cdot ^4C_2= ^7C_3\cdot \frac{3!}{3}\cdot 6$ ways, which is exactly double of what you have suggested. Would you check if there's a mistake somewhere in reasoning in either case?